# How to run cucumber jvm report using io.cucumber

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

### I updated my POM.xml with io.cucumber  .my Pom below:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


         <groupId>ToolsQA</groupId>
        <artifactId>CucumberFramework</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>CucumberFramework</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>   -->
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.14.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.6</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
        <!--    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
                <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </dependency>  -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/datatable-dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatable-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/datatable-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>  -->
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-html -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </dependency> 
        </dependencies>

        <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.19.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore> 

                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                            <version>3.15.0</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>execution</id>
                                    <phase>verify</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>generate</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <projectName>cucumber-jvm-example</projectName>
                                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/Cucumber-JVM-report</outputDirectory>
                                        <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                                         <!-- <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports/cucumber-json</inputDirectory> -->
                                        <jsonFiles>
                        <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                        <param>**/*.json</param>
                    </jsonFiles>
                    <skippedFails>true</skippedFails>
                    <enableFlashCharts>true</enableFlashCharts>
                    <buildNumber>10.2.1</buildNumber>
                                        <checkBuildResult>true</checkBuildResult>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>

    </project>
```

### and my runner class using the below code

```
package testRunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;



import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
//import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import cucumber.api.testng.CucumberFeatureWrapper;
import cucumber.api.testng.PickleEventWrapper;
//import cucumber.api.testng.PickleEventWrapper;
import cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {
        "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html","html:target/Cucumber-JVM-report","json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json"}, features = "src/test/java/Features", monochrome = true, tags = {
                "@US_IEITF-6646_AttachDocAndPreviewandSubmit,@US_IEITF-6441_Exit" }, glue = "stepDef", strict = true)
public class TestRunner {
//extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTestsests 
    public static WebDriver driver;
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testRunner;
    public ExtentTest log = null;
    private Scenario scenario;

//  @BeforeClass
//  public void before(Scenario scenario) {
//        this.scenario = scenario;
//  }

    /*@BeforeClass
    public void setUP() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        testRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(TestRunner.class);

    }
    */
    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void precondition() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        testRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());

    }


    /*@Test(description = "login", dataProvider = "features")
    public void login(CucumberFeatureWrapper cFeature) {
        testRunner.runCucumber(cFeature.getCucumberFeature());

    }
    */
    @Test(groups = "cucumber scenarios", description = "login", dataProvider = "scenarios")
            public void scenario(PickleEventWrapper pickleEvent, CucumberFeatureWrapper 
            cucumberFeature) throws Throwable{
        testRunner.runScenario(pickleEvent.getPickleEvent());
            }
    /*@DataProvider(name = "features")
    public Object[][] getFeatures() {
        return testRunner.provideFeatures();
    }*/

    @DataProvider(name = "scenarios")
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return testRunner.provideScenarios();
    }


    /*@AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {

        testRunner.finish();

        Reporter.loadXMLConfig("./extent-config.xml");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("User Name", System.getProperty("user.name"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Time Zone", System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Machine", "Windows 10" + "64 Bit");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Selenium", "3.7.0");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Maven", "3.5.2");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Java Version", "1.8.0_151");
    }*/
    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        testRunner.finish();
        Reporter.loadXMLConfig("./extent-config.xml");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("User Name", System.getProperty("user.name"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Time Zone", System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Machine", "Windows 10" + "64 Bit");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Selenium", "3.7.0");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Maven", "3.5.2");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Java Version", "1.8.0_151");
    }
}
```

### getting console error as below

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\nikita_khanna01\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-2024013776\testng-customsuite.xml

[Utils] Attempting to create D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\Default suite\Default test.xml
[Utils]   Directory D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\Default suite exists: true
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass precondition
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber/runtime/BackendModuleBackendSupplier.<init>(Lcucumber/runtime/io/ResourceLoader;Lcucumber/runtime/ClassFinder;Lcucumber/runtime/RuntimeOptions;)V (loaded from file:/D:/maven_repo/io/cucumber/cucumber-core/4.3.1/cucumber-core-4.3.1.jar by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@fac6da36) called from class cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner (loaded from file:/D:/maven_repo/io/cucumber/cucumber-testng/4.2.0/cucumber-testng-4.2.0.jar by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@fac6da36).
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.<init>(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:54)
    at testRunner.TestRunner.precondition(TestRunner.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:216)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:143)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:169)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:753)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:607)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:368)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:363)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:321)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:270)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1284)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1209)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tearDownClass
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at testRunner.TestRunner.tearDownClass(TestRunner.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:216)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:143)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:217)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:115)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:753)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:607)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:368)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:363)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:321)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:270)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1284)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1209)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)

SKIPPED: scenario
         login
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:110)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:436)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1253)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:980)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1070)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:753)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:607)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:368)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:363)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:321)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:270)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1284)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1209)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at testRunner.TestRunner.scenarios(TestRunner.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:51)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:41)
    ... 22 more


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@4a44115: 20 ms
[Utils] Attempting to create D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\testng-failed.xml
[Utils]   Directory D:\Form10E_GH\test-output exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\Default suite\testng-failed.xml
[Utils]   Directory D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\Default suite exists: true
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 15 ms
[Utils] Attempting to create D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\junitreports\TEST-testRunner.TestRunner.xml
[Utils]   Directory D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\junitreports exists: true
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@1ddcb11b: 10 ms
[Utils] Attempting to create D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite\toc.html
[Utils]   Directory D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite\Default test.properties
[Utils]   Directory D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite\index.html
[Utils]   Directory D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite\main.html
[Utils]   Directory D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite\groups.html
[Utils]   Directory D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite\classes.html
[Utils]   Directory D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite\reporter-output.html
[Utils]   Directory D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite\methods-not-run.html
[Utils]   Directory D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite\testng.xml.html
[Utils]   Directory D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old\index.html
[Utils]   Directory D:\Form10E_GH\test-output\old exists: true
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@9ad48bdc: 44 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@cb0ee652: 16 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@5d5ba3a5: 235 ms

please check above code and let me know what I am doing wrong here
```

also let me how to run this Run as- TestNG suite from Runner or Run as Maven Install through POM.xml
I want to update my project with io.cucumber and then run test runner to genearte tabular form report 
I dont want to use POM.xml while running report instead want TestNG to be used 
Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

This error is often the result of conflicting Cucumber dependencies.

1. Use the same version of your Cucumber dependencies. 
   This means updating the following:

   io.cucumber
       cucumber-testng
       **4.2.0**

to version 4.3.1 you are using in other places.

2. In addition, you are importing several dependencies that should be managed as transitive dependencies of those Cucumber dependencies.

Please remove the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

io.cucumber
        datatable-dependencies
        1.1.12

```
<!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/datatable-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

io.cucumber
        cucumber-core
        4.3.1

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
<!--<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>  -->
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-html -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Some additional tips:
* In order to make sure you use the same version of Cucumber, also when upgrading, add the following:
    
        4.3.1

and use `<version>${cucumber.version}</version>` for all of your Cucumber dependencies. 
* Version 4.3.1 is no longer the latest; I think the latest is 4.8.0 (if you want to upgrade)
* Use either TestNg or JUnit (and remove the other).
* In general, don't keep commented out code/config in your project. That's what version control is for :)

Comment: I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin.formatter.Reporter error now after doing changes in my POM.xml

Comment: How are you running your tests?

Comment: That might also be related to the reporter plugin you are using. Could you try running with a built-in report first to rule out that's a Cucumber problem? (Sidenote: I highly recommend using [Cluecumber](https://github.com/trivago/cluecumber-report-plugin) report)